# simple combinatorics: product rule and number of ordered pairs

Tags: combinatorics

Product rule: if $X,Y$ -- finite sets and $|X|=n$, $|Y|= m$ we can say, that the number of the ways to first extract an element from the first set and then an element from the second set $= nm$ -- direct product of sets $X$ and $Y$.

${n+m}\choose{2}$$2!= \frac{(n+m)!}{2! (n+m-2)!} = \frac{(n+m)(n+m-1)}{2}$ --the number of non-ordered pairs in set $X\cup Y$, where $|X\cup Y| = n + m$.

What the difference between these two formulas? I cannot see... Why $\frac{(n+m)(n+m-1)}{2} \neq nm$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first scenario, there is one case: One element from $X$, one element from $Y$. That's the only type of pair you're going to get.

In the second scenario, there are three cases:

- Two elements from $X$
- Two elements from $Y$
- One element from $X$, one element from $Y$

This is why there are more pairs in the second scenario than the first.

Comment: Ou, oh, ye!

Thx :D

Comment: It might be worth saying that $\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2} +\dfrac{m(m-1)}{2} +nm = \dfrac{(n+m)(n+m-1)}{2}$

Comment: @Henry nice, $=$ ${n}\choose{2}$ $+$ ${m}\choose{2}$ $+$ $nm$

Comment: @Henry also clear, that if we use not direct product, but free product $X \oplus X$, if $x_i \in X$ we will be have two words in $X\oplus X$ $(x_i, x_i) \neq (x_i, x_i)$ that equal in $X^2$ and in this formula we will be write ${n}\choose{2}$$2!$ $+$ ${m}\choose{2}$$2!$ $+$ $nm$